# How can make a ARM64 Vm works with Cockpit from a AMD64 ubuntu computer?

Tags: virtual-machine, x86-64, qemu, arm64, cockpit

So I am trying to make a virtual machine of a raspios-bullseye-arm64.
By using Qemu on my ubuntu 22.04 Lts x86_64, I was able to see the raspberry terminal.
I could not access to that VM because the default user and pw didn´t work. (but at least I know it launch)

So now my main goal was to get Cockpit to work and integrate the Cockpit-machines.
That part was easy and now I can make the amd64 machines without problem.

Now my goal is to get the arm64 machines to work with cockpit but I am not able to.

I don't know if it will be possible or I will have to get another machine with arm64 architecture to install the cockpit and have the arm64 and amd64 separated in two different machines.

Hope you guys can help me because nothing seems to solve my problem on my research.

I already tried to change the CPU configuration.
Also the boot order.
It keeps getting me the error of no bootable decive.
I am sure this is because of the difference of architecture.

Comment: Seems like more of a sysadmin question about installing and configuring software, not about writing programs.  Perhaps on-topic on https://serverfault.com/, but it's a bit vague on details about exactly what you tried as far as a [mcve].

Comment: Well not everything on stackoverflow is about writing programs. I will try asking in serverfault.com too.
The simplify question is:
Is there anyway I can run an arm64 VM using Cockpit on a amd64 machine?